# 'ggbApplet is not defined' error in javascript

Tags: javascript, geogebra

I have a web page which include a geogebra applet. On loading the page I would like to modify certain elements in the applet, depending on user input. I tested the following code

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var parameters = {
   "width":600,"height":450,
   "filename":"trois_ensembles.ggb"};

var applet = new GGBApplet('5.0', parameters);

window.onload = function() {
    applet.inject('applet_container');
    ggbApplet.setVisible('A', false);
}
</script>
```

But the line

```
ggbApplet.setVisible('A', false);
```

produces an error in the console

> ReferenceError: ggbApplet is not defined

When `ggbApplet` is referenced elsewhere, as in

```
   <button onclick="ggbApplet.setVisible('A', true)">Set A </button>
```

everything works as expected.

I don't understand the scope of `ggbApplet`. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking *Global JavaScript* section of [Scripting](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Scripting) page of Geogebra's wiki may be useful.

Cheers.

See this section:

> Note: Using any ggbApplet methods in Global JavaScript outside of ggbOnInit will not work as intended since they will be called before the construction is loaded.

Comment: Thanks, solved my problem. I moved the code to ggbOnInit.